# Prove $H$ is a proper normal subgroup of $G$ if $H$ is generated by $\{[x,y] \mid x,y \in G\} \cup \{x^p \mid x \in G\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, nilpotent-groups

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $G$ be a nontrivial finite $p$-group, where $p$ is a prime, and let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by the set $\{[x,y] \mid x,y \in G\} \cup \{x^p \mid x \in G\}$.
>
> Prove that $H$ is a proper normal subgroup of $G$.

It is not hard to see that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Indeed, any element of $g \in G$ commutes with any element of the commutator. Moreover, $gx^pg^{-1} = (gxg^{-1})^p$. Since any generator of $H$ commutes with any element of $G$, the same is true for $H$. However, I do not know how to prove $H \neq G$.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note first that $[G,G]$ is a proper subgroup of $G$ and that $H/[G,G]$ is just the subgroup of $G/[G,G]$ generated by $p$th powers (why?).  So, we may replace $G$ with $G/[G,G]$ and thus assume $G$ is abelian.  But if $G$ is abelian then $H$ is just the set of $p$th powers, and so any element of $G$ of maximal order will not be in $H$.

Comment: We can say $H/[G,G]$ is the subgroup of $G/[G,G]$ generated by $p$th powers because $p$ divides $G/[G,G]$; so, Cauchy's theorem ensures there is an element of order $p$ in $G/[G,G]$. Am I right @EricWofsey?

Comment: @Peter: No, that's totally wrong.  Why would it be relevant whether there is an element of order $p$?  To prove the claim about $H/[G,G]$, you'll need to use the definition of $H$.

Comment: you are totally right!, but I don't see why $H \neq [G,G]$. This is also irrelevant as I was asked to prove $H$ is proper; so, it does not matter whether $H \neq [G,G]$ or not but I am just curious.

Comment: It is entirely possible that $H=[G,G]$; I never said it wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that any generator of $H$ commutes with any element of $G$; rather, an element of $G$ conjugates any generator of $H$ to another generator of $H$.

As for why $H<G$, note that $G'\le H$.  Now in $G/G'$, which is abelian, the subgroup generated by $p$th powers on one hand is proper. In fact, it's just the $p$th powers and so excludes all elements of maximal order.  On the other hand, it's clearly equal to $H/G'$.  Thus, since $H/G'<G/G'$ we have $H<G$.